# Using curl to get dns/connect/send/wait/receive times of url

Tags: curl

I need help picking the right curl functions to calculate these things:

```
DNS The web browser is looking up DNS information
Connect The web browser is connecting to the server
Send    The web browser is sending data to the server
Wait    The web browser is waiting for data from the server
Receive The web browser is receiving data from the server
```

For example if i have this url `http://g2.delfi.lt/scms/?g=delfi-fp.css&1362823940` , i would want to get these values:

```
DNS - 443ms
Connect - 589ms
Send - 1ms
Wait - 152ms
Receive - 1ms
```

Can i do this using curl?

Answer (score 0):

The curl can easy get the dns,connect time.wait=TOTAL?

Answer (score 0):

Using both the curl command line tool or libcurl you will need some post-processing.

curl exposes the following times:

```
curl_easy_perform()
     |
     |--NAMELOOKUP
     |--|--CONNECT
     |--|--|--APPCONNECT
     |--|--|--|--PRETRANSFER
     |--|--|--|--|--STARTTRANSFER
     |--|--|--|--|--|--TOTAL
     |--|--|--|--|--|--REDIRECT
```

*Programmatically* you can use:

```
CURLcode curl_easy_getinfo(CURL *curl, CURLINFO info, ... );
```

to retrieve them. Details [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html)

Using the *curl cli tool* you can print all the above values using the **--write-out** option
You will then need to do some really simple math to get the time deltas you need.